# VueJS can compare Multiple value use v-if like php array

Tags: javascript, vue.js

VueJS Multiple Condition v-if

```
<div v:if="value.id === ['1','2']">
     print "pass"
</div>
```

can use this or define syntax any ??

Comment: Use `includes` method. `<div v-if="['1', '2'].includes(value.id)">{{}}</div>`

Comment: get it !! Thx. am baby vue dev.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to S/O!

I understand the thing you wish to achieve is to check whether id matches some kind of id in array.

In JS for arrays you can use the `.includes()` array prototype method to compare and check whether value exists in the array. In your case you could write it like this – `[1, 2].includes(value.id)`

You can also create more complex if statements by calling a defined Vue method in `v-if`; say you would have a `isSomething()` method that returns a boolean defined in Vue, you could call it in template by `v-if="isSomething(someValue)"`

You can check Vue docs for further reference –
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#methods